# Redefining the section command, keeping the starred definition

Tags: sectioning, starred-version

Currently, I'm working with a document based on the standard `book.cls`. I redefined the section command (unstarred) to get a more fancy heading. But while doing this, I ran into some walls.

```
\renewcommand{\section}{\secdef\@section\@ssection}
\newcommand{\@section}[2][?]{...}
```

Well obviously, I've redefined the unstarred version with `\@section`, and together with `\secdef` I fixed bugs in the ToC (strange doublings) and tried to keep the definition of the starred version. To make it short, it doesn't work... here is the output:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@a *->\@ssection
```

Does anybody know how to handle it? Even `\let` doesn't help here...

Comment: Sectioning command below `\chapter` (`\section`, `\subsection`, ...) do not have a separate "starred" version, like you propose `\@ssection`. You have to define that manually, like is done for `\chapter` and `\part`.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that shows what you've done in its entirety?

Answer (score 13):

`\section` is *not* defined via `\secdef`. So there is no `\@ssection`.

This may work:

```
\makeatletter
\let\latex@section\section
\def\section{\secdef\my@section{\latex@section*}}

\def\my@section[#1]#2{...}

\makeatother
```

So `\section*` will call `\latex@section*`, while `\section{title}` will call

```
\my@section[title]{title}
```

while `\section[x]{title}` will call

```
\my@section[x]{title}
```