# Have command's output dependent on where (body or section title) it is called

Tags: macros

I am using

```
\newcommand{\PRODUCT}{\textsf{PRODUCT}}
```

to format a product name consistently throughout my document. However, I realized that this should not happen in (((sub-)sub-)sub-)section titles, but there really should just the text be printed without formatting, as in

```
\newcommand{\PRODUCT}{PRODUCT}
```

How can I have a command result in different outputs depending on where it is used in the document?

Comment: I don't see why: you're going against consistency.

Comment: I know, but it was not my idea...

Comment: Unfortunately there's no standard way to tell whether LaTeX is typesetting a title or normal text. The simplest workaround would be to provide a `*`-variant to be used in titles.

Comment: @egreg titles are usually in bold face, one could test for that.

Comment: @jfbu But also normal text can be.

Comment: @masu I don't answer *all* questions.

Comment: @egreg ((I know, but (as I've seen yet) you answer most of the unanswered questions where you care to comment)). My solution is all-right? I'll remove the end part then and continue being satisfied.

Comment: @navige What about the table of contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As egreg told you, "there's no standard way to tell whether LaTeX is typesetting a title or normal text". However you can do some "hacking":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\titleFLAG=0

\newcommand\emphif[1]{%
    \ifx1\titleFLAG#1\else\textsf{#1}\fi
}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@section\section
\def\section{\secdef\my@section{\latex@section}}
\def\my@section[#1]#2{\let\titleFLAG=1\latex@section[#1]{#2}\let\titleFLAG=0}
\let\latex@subsection\subsection
\def\subsection{\secdef\my@subsection{\latex@subsection}}
\def\my@subsection[#1]#2{\let\titleFLAG=1\latex@subsection[#1]{#2}\let\titleFLAG=0}
\let\latex@subsubsection\subsubsection
\def\subsubsection{\secdef\my@subsubsection{\latex@subsubsection}}
\def\my@subsubsection[#1]#2{\let\titleFLAG=1\latex@subsubsection[#1]{#2}\let\titleFLAG=0}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
ABCD \emphif{TEST} ABCD

\section{ABCD \emphif{TEST} ABCD}

ABCD \emphif{TEST} ABCD

\subsection{ABCD \emphif{TEST} ABCD}

ABCD \emphif{TEST} ABCD

\subsubsection{ABCD \emphif{TEST} ABCD}

ABCD \emphif{TEST} ABCD

\noindent
{\bfseries ABCD \emphif{TEST} ABCD}

\end{document}
```

Hopefully @egreg will tell us what can backfire here and why is this a really bad idea to do. Until that, this seems to work and you only have to add code to your preamble. :)

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/77906/36821).

Comment: I'd do it slightly differently, but not in an essential way. You need no braces in `\secdef\my@section\latex@section`.

Comment: looks truly like hacking :) but if it works its fine :)

Answer (score 3):

This is essentially the same as masu's answer; what's added is an abstraction layer that allows to say only

```
\redef\section
\redef\subsection
```

and so on, ensuring that all sectional commands we need are redefined in the same way; code duplication is thus avoided. I added also a `\productdef` command with three arguments: the first is a control sequence name, the second is what we want to be done in titles and the third is what we want in normal text.

It remains a problem to be solved: what should be the behavior of `\PRODUCT` in the table of contents? With the following macros it will use the “normal text” version. It would be easy to change `\tableofcontents` so that it sets the conditional too.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\redef}{m}
 {
  \navige_redef:N #1
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \navige_redef:N #1
 {
  % get a copy of the command to modify
  \cs_set_eq:cN { latex_original_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :w } #1
  % redefine it with the common “som” strategy, but setting the
  % conditional to true before calling the old command
  \RenewDocumentCommand{ #1 } { s o m }
   {
    \bool_gset_true:N \g_navige_intitle_bool
    \IfBooleanTF{##1}
     {
      \use:c { latex_original_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :w } * { ##3 }
     }
     {
      \IfNoValueTF{##2}
       {
        \use:c { latex_original_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :w } { ##3 }
       }
       {
        \use:c { latex_original_ \cs_to_str:N #1 :w } [ ##2 ] { ##3 }
       }
     }
    % end by setting the conditional to false
    \bool_gset_false:N \g_navige_intitle_bool
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\productdef}{mmm}
 {
  \cs_new_protected:Npn #1
   {
    \bool_if:NTF \g_navige_intitle_bool { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\redef\section
\redef\subsection
\redef\subsubsection

\productdef{\PRODUCT}{PRODUCT}{\textsf{PRODUCT}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\show\section
\section*{Introduction about \PRODUCT}

Abcd \PRODUCT{} abcd

\section{Abcd \PRODUCT{} abcd}

Abcd \PRODUCT{} abcd

\subsection{Abcd \PRODUCT{} abcd}

Abcd \PRODUCT{} abcd

\subsubsection{Abcd \PRODUCT{} abcd}

Abcd \PRODUCT{} abcd

{\bfseries Abcd \PRODUCT{} abcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]